# Observablelist and arraylist, different behavior

Tags: java, collections, javafx

I'm working with a javafx listview in muliple selection mode, specifically a method which deletes selected items in the list.

the method with a observablelist

```
    list.getItems()
            .removeAll(
                    list.getSelectionModel()
                    .getSelectedItems());
```

the method with an array list

```
    list.getItems()
            .removeAll(new ArrayList<Object>(
                            list.getSelectionModel()
                            .getSelectedItems()));
```

Why would these implementations produce different results?
The arraylist implementation removes only selected items.
The observablelist implementation removes everything after the first selected item, whether it's selected or not.

Could this be a bug in the javafx removeAll method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObservableList` is backed by the actual model, and as such changes along with the listview *while* the entries are removed. By first copying the selected elements to an `ArrayList`, you eliminate the problem: the created `ArrayList` does not depend on the listview, and as such does not change during the `removeAll` operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.getItems().removeAll(
    new ArrayList<Object>(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
```

This is creating an `ArrayList<Object>` whose `Object` it contains is another type of list structure.

---

So in your first case the `list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` gets a list of items and the `.removeAll` looks through that list to see which items to remove.

In the second case the `new ArrayList<Object>(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems())` is an `ArrayList` of a list - the `.removeAll` looks for that list within the list that calls it.